# Parsing keys in ajax returned json array

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Hello i have returned array in json from jquery ajax call of php file. This array looks like this :

```
array(
'LANG_PORTFOLIO'=>'Portfolio',
'LANG_ABOUT'=>'Company',
);
```

is it possible somehow to get also first key dynamically?

In my jquery success code i have this :

```
 success: function (data) {
        alert(data[0][0]);
        alert(data.[1]);
        alert(data.LANG_PORTFOLIO);
 }
```

Only last mentioned works. But i cant use it dynamically.

I want to achieve something like this :

```
 for(var i in data){
     var key=data[0] //first key
     $("element[lang='"+key+"']").text(data.key); //add text with active language
 }
```

// i set lang parameter of elements equal to array 'leftside' keys.

Any help? Thanks

Comment: For what purpose you need first key?  var key=data[0]

Comment: because this key equals to my elements attributes and thos i can change their content dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there's no *special* thing for that, but you can use:

```
for (key in data) break;
//now key will be first key of your object
```

Thus, your loop will be like:

```
for(var i in data)
{
    for (key in data[i]) break; //first key of data[i]
    //here is why I doubt: data[i], but data.key ??
    $("element[lang='"+key+"']").text(data.key); 
}
```

(I'm not sure about logic, that's what I see from question's post. Especially I'm doubt because your JSON in PHP is 1D-array while in JSON you're operating on 2D)

Comment: and this should be inner loop? substition for var key=data[0]?

Comment: I've updated, yep. The idea is to use `for..in` and break after first iteration

Comment: oh i'll try it :) will get back soon

Comment: Both of replies works. But u know 'key' is just pseudo. I dont have to do it in 2 steps but i wanted u to understand my purpose :)

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var i in data){     
     $("element[lang='"+i+"']").text(data.[i]); //add text with active language
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this way to split your JSON array

```
success:function(data){
    $.each(data,function(key,value){
      $("element[lang='"+key+"']").text(value.LANG_PORTFOLIO);
    });
}
```